# SQL - update field if greater than 500

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE alterFieldSize @column NVARCHAR(MAX), @table NVARCHAR(MAX), @prsColumnLen INT
AS
-- DECLARE VARIABLES
    DECLARE @sql        NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @fieldLen   INT
    DECLARE @columnLen  INT

-- SET VARIABLES
SET     @fieldLen   = @prsColumnLen
SET     @columnLen  = (SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE @column AND TABLE_NAME LIKE @table)
SET     @fieldLen   = CASE WHEN @columnLen > @fieldLen THEN @columnLen WHEN @fieldLen <=500 THEN @fieldLen ELSE 500 END
SET     @sql        = 'ALTER TABLE Client ALTER COLUMN '+ @column + ' NVARCHAR('+cast(@fieldLen as VARCHAR(20))+')'


-- Execution
EXEC(@sql)
```

Which is then called via:

```
SET @fieldLen   = (SELECT MAX(LEN(s.StreetAddress)) FROM [DB1].dbo.Sites s)
EXEC alterFieldSize @column = 'ClientAddress',      @table = 'Client',  @prsColumnLen = @fieldLen
```

Ofcourse this runs into issues because if the field values are set to 500 then i cant insert the data accross due to the field being too small in size unless i do this manually on each insert statement. What i want is to take everything after the 500th character out if the field is set to 500 during that case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Let me make certain I understand what you want to do.  If I called this stored procedure with parameters like: `EXEC alterFieldSize 'Data1', 'Table1', 666`, and the @columnLen was 600, this would result in shrinking Data1 to 500 characters. Before that happens, you want to trim the actual data in the field to a maximum of 500 characters. Is that about it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding this but isn't this just a matter of updating the table (e.g. `update mytable set mycol = left(mycol, 500)`) before running the procedure?

Comment: Quite honestly, wouldn't it be safer to generate an error in this case, and let the user work out what needs to happen independently of this proc?

Comment: @Laughing Vergil  You are probably correct, I have done very little error checking with SQL and i know the error you get from SQL Server doesnt help. Doesnt tell you which field would be truncated just that one will be, if i can get an error that shows me exactly what field is the issue that would work too.

Comment: And yes i want to trim the fields to a certain value dependent on the field it wouldnt always be 500. This is simply because people have input their life story into address and mobile fields which didnt have a data limit. Now i have a mobile number field that has a length of 8150 characters.

Comment: Then I admit to a bit of confusion. The code allows the maximum length of the data in the column to override the specified column length. In the case of your mobile number field, this code would attempt to set the field length to 8150 -- which would be illegal, what with varchar holding a maximum of 8000 characters unless declared as varchar(max). I'm thinking that this needs to be a multi-pass process, where the final code  to be executed is decided manually.

Comment: Conceptually, this is a good basis for your process, with a simple `LEFT()` call on the data field if the actual data is being truncated. However, real world circumstances (8150 character long phone numbers, for example) can override conceptual perfection.

Comment: The first part of the case will override the column length to the length of the column i am inserting data into yes, these columns have a set lengths of around 250 - 500 so it will only override it if the length is lower in the old database than that of the new one. Sorry if im not making much sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131756/discussion-between-owain-esau-and-laughing-vergil).

Comment: Is there a reason why `left()` doesn't work?

Comment: LEFT() does work, but the issue is that there could be 10 - 100 columns by the end of the script that cannot be inserted due to the field size. I could add LEFT() to every single field on each insert statement but i feel like that is messy. What LaughingVergil said about having an error message that displays which column being inserted is the issue would resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Variant 1:** create new persisted computed column with maximal lenght of 500

```
alter table add NewPersistedColumn as (left(YourColumn, 500) persisted
```

**Variant 2:** make instead of insert trigger with left function

```
create trigger trg_table on trg_table
instead of insert
as
insert into table (col, col2) select left(col, 500), col2 from inserted.*
```

Best solution is to avoid this string in your app. Your solution should depend on your purpose of longer and shorter field.